# Timer onClick Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to do some hidden menu implementation. Something like Developers options in Android OS where you press 10 times and it opens a secret menu.

MY task is to make a onbutton click listener that fires some kind of timer event. I have to click that button 10 times and the secret menu will appear. What is more it should have 8 second reset timer that resets the clicks if the user didnt press the button in 8 seconds. I understand it should be done on worker thread but I have a problem finding best practices and classes for this kind of work.

Comment: Forget the timer. Just save the timestamp of last click. When clicked, compare actual vs saved. If difference > 8 secs reset counter.

Answer (score 2):

You need not to actually implement timer here, just keep a note of time when user hits the button and compare the difference everytime if it is under 8 seconds, reset otherwise.

Assume you have some method like `manageAction()`

```
long lastHitTime;
int counter;
boolean manageAction() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastHitTime <= 8000) {
        counter++;
        return counter>=10;

    }
    counter=0;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you could also add the counter, than the example would be very cool ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int clickCount = 0;
    private int maxClick = 10;
    private Toast mToast;
    private long clickDelayTime = 500; // milli second (if you want to set 8 sec then set 8000 instead of 500)
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(clickDelayTime, clickDelayTime) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // set click count to 0 if user stop clicking before timer finish
            clickCount = 0;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView tvClick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvClick);
        tvClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // increment click count
                clickCount++;
                // cancel previous timer
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                // start new timer after next click
                mCountDownTimer.start();

                if (clickCount == maxClick) {
                    // cancel current toast
                    mToast.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have clicked " + clickCount + " times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    clickCount = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // create toast is null
                if (mToast == null) {
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click " + (maxClick - clickCount) + " more times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                } else {
                    // if toast is not null then update message
                    mToast.setText("Click " + (maxClick - clickCount) + " more times.");
                }
                mToast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like your task, so just try this.

first declare two parameters, one counts your hit times, the other indicates whether hit times should be reset.

```
int hitTimes = 0;
boolean isTheFirstHit = true;
```

then, add listener and create the method to count hit times.

```
    YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showSecretMenu();
            countTimes();
        }
    });

private void countTimes(){

    if (isTheFirstHit){

        Log.d("YOUR TAG", "hitTimes = " + hitTimes);
        isTheFirstHit = false;

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d("YOUR TAG", "start time: " + start);

                while (true){
                    SystemClock.sleep(500);
                    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (end - start > 8000 ){
                        isTheFirstHit = true;
                        clickTimes = 0;
                        Log.d("YOUR TAG", "reset hitTimes after 8 seconds");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

then, show your secret menu when you constantly hit the button 8 times

```
private void showSecretMenu(){

    hitTimes++;
    Log.d("YOUR TAG", "current hit times = " + hitTimes);

    if (hitTimes == 8 && !isTheFirstHit){
        // SHOW YOUR SECRET MENU HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (clicks == 0) {
        clickCountStartTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }

    long endTime = clickCountStartTime + 3000;
    if (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() > endTime) {
        clicks = 0;
    }

    if (clicks == 10) {
//Code of your intent, toast or whatever action goes here

        clicks = 0;
    }

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                clicks++;
            }
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I managed with your help guys.

```
private long startTime;
private boolean isClicked = false;
private short clickCount;     

tvPhoneTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!isClicked) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                isClicked = true;
                clickCount++;
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 10000) {
                clickCount++;
                if (clickCount == 8) {
                    //DO SOMETHING
                    clickCount = 0;
                }

            } else {
                clickCount = 0;
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }
    });
```